# How can I prevent statements from being output multiple times when SQL tracing is enabled with DBI?

Tags: mysql, perl, trace, dbi

After connecting to a MySQL database using [`DBI`](http://metacpan.org/module/DBI) I enable [trace](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#TRACING) like this

```
$dbh->trace('SQL|DBD');
```

Then after this my SQL queries are printed twice:

```
>count_params statement SELECT table1.ID ID, table1.LinkID LinkID, Link.ID Link_ID FROM `table1` `table1` JOIN `table2` `Link` ON `table1`.`LinkID` = `Link`.`ID` WHERE table1.ID = ?
>parse_params statement SELECT table1.ID ID, table1.LinkID LinkID, Link.ID Link_ID FROM `table1` `table1` JOIN `table2` `Link` ON `table1`.`LinkID` = `Link`.`ID` WHERE table1.ID = ?
```

How can I print every executed SQL statement only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I print every executed SQL statement only once?

You can't. `count_params` and `parse_params` are internal functions used by DBD::mysql to emulate prepared statements on the client. Both are called when you execute a prepared statement.

[`count_params`](https://metacpan.org/source/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.033/dbdimp.c#L76) is called when a statement is prepared and contains the following:

```
if (DBIc_DBISTATE(imp_xxh)->debug >= 2)
  PerlIO_printf(DBIc_LOGPIO(imp_xxh), ">count_params statement %s\n", statement);
```

[`parse_params`](https://metacpan.org/source/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.033/dbdimp.c#L521) is called when a statement is executed and contains the following:

```
if (DBIc_DBISTATE(imp_xxh)->debug >= 2)
  PerlIO_printf(DBIc_LOGPIO(imp_xxh), ">parse_params statement %s\n", statement);
```

The logic is the same for both, so it's either all or nothing.

Comment: When I say "you can't", I mean there's no built-in way to do this with DBD::mysql. If it really bothers you, you can filter stderr, e.g. `perl myscript.pl 2>&1 | grep -v '>count_params'`